# How can I create an instance of <div> in my JSX function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Heres my code:

```
const drops = 500;
const rain = [];
for (let i = 0; i < drops; i++) {
    let rainDrops = '<div class="drop" id="drop' + i + '"></div>';
    let left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (16000 - 0 + 1)) + 1;
    let top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (-1000 - 1400 + 1)) + 1;

}
console.log(rain)


const NavBar = () => (
    <div>
        <section className="rain"
            left={left}
            top={top} >
            {rain}
        </section>
    </div>
);
export default NavBar;
```

Im trying to populate my page with rain drops populated by randomizing the occurrence of a `<section>` which is inside a JSX function then I am exporting it at the end.

When I `yarn start` it gives my console a syntax error.  Saying further that `left is undefined` and `Unexpected use of top`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have declare veriables in for loop.

Comment: add rainDrops in rain array. rain.push(rainDrops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to make your code work. Here's the one to understand React better without going too deep in state and props concept.

```
const drops = 500;
const rainDrops = []; // <-- let's rename this
for (let i = 0; i < drops; i++) {
    let left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (16000 - 0 + 1)) + 1; // Subtract zero?
    let top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (-1000 - 1400 + 1)) + 1;
    rainDrops.push({ left, top }); // <-- Collect every drop
}
console.log(rainDrops); // ok, why not. But let's always add a semicolon


const NavBar = () => (
    <div>
        <section className="rain">
            {rainDrops.map(({ left, top }, index) =>
                <div
                    className="drop"
                    id={'drop' + index}
                    style={{ left: left + 'px', top: top + 'px', }}
                />
            )}
        </section>
    </div>
);
export default NavBar;
```

Comment: This was my pseudo coded idea but just dont know the syntax as to how to type the code to work.  `collect the drop` that way is great to know.  The trouble I had was in the `const Navbar` where you solved the `style` that I originally intend to achieve.  THANK YOU.

Comment: The trouble I had was in the `const Navbar` where you added the `.map` and solved the `style` problem I had originally thought to do but dont know the correct syntax.  Again THANK YOU - it is the solution to the problem.